# reading a csv file in NetLogo

Tags: csv, netlogo

I have a problem with reading a CSV format file which is named Window.csv in NetLogo. Would you please guide me step by step to import the CSV file? My first question: I must put this file in a specific folder or not and how to introduce the location of the file to  NetLogo?
I tried some ways:
1- writing this code in observer:

```
csv:from-file "/C:/Program Files/NetLogo 6.0.3/to/Window.csv"
```

I faced this error: Nothing named CSV:FROM-FILE has been defined. 
2- I tried this code in code space in NetLogo:

```
set filename “C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.3\Window.csv”
to-report sum-columns [ file ]
  file-open file
  set result csv:from-row file-read-line
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let row csv:from-row file-read-line
    set result (map [?1 + ?2] result row)
  ]
  file-close
  report result
end
```

I faced this error: keyword expected
3- I tried this code that I found on this site:

```
extensions [csv]
globals [data variable]
to setup
file-close-all 
file-open "Window.csv"
;; read the data all at once by using csv:from-file
set data csv:from-file "Window.csv"
reset-ticks
end

to go
if file-at-end? [stop]
;; extract value from the list, using item 0 to remove the list, and just keep the value
set variable item 0 item ticks data
tick  
if ticks = length data [stop]
show variable
end
```

but nothing happened.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It can be in any folder. However, you need to include the path as well as the filename. You have copied the text from the documentation without understanding it and the path doesn't make sense. What folder is your file "Window.csv" actually stored in?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to have both your NetLogo model (.nlogo) and your CSV file (.csv) saved in the same folder, something like this:

[image]

Then, you can use the `csv` extension as you started in your second example like so:

```
extensions [csv]
globals [ data ]

to setup
  ca
  set data csv:from-file "example_data.csv"
  print data
  reset-ticks
end
```

After running that code you have your example data stored in the `data` variable. You can also use relative addressing in a similar way. For example, if you have data stored in a folder in the same folder as your model:

[image]

where the `data_folder` contains the CSV file you want to load, you can do

```
set data csv:from-file "data_folder/example_data.csv"
```

If you don't know where the file is in relation to where your model is stored, you can always provide the full address. If I have a folder on my C drive called "data_folder" that contains my "example_data.csv", I can call that like so:

```
set data csv:from-file "C:/data_folder/example_data.csv"
```

**Edit- more detail:**

I'll show you what output I get from my first example above Using this example .csv:

[image]

That file, called "example_data.csv" is stored in the same folder as my NetLogo file. In my NetLogo file all I have is:

```
extensions [csv]
globals [ data ]

to setup
  ca
  set data csv:from-file "example_data.csv"
  print data
  reset-ticks
end
```

Then, on my interface I put a button called `setup` to call the procedure above on the interface:

[image]

If I push the `setup` button, the code is executed and the `print data` statement is run, so that in the Command Center I see the results:

[image]

From that, you can see that the .csv has been loaded such that each line is stored as a list within the list called `data`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I did all steps but, I couldn`t see the get output and bring the CSV data in my code space.

Comment: @Sina Sorry to hear that, but you'll need to provide much more information for me or other users here to be able to help out. For example, what didn't work? Did you get an error message? Where is your NetLogo file stored, and where is your CSV file stored? What approach of the examples above did you try?

Comment: Again and again, I appreciate for your help, I have a folder in desktop that has a CSV file format and my model NetLogo file. Then I copied all codes same as above. I didn't get any errors but the CSV file hasn't inserted in code space. I wanna know that about CSV extension. Do I download the CSV extension and copy it in this address: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.4\app\extensions\csv? I downloaded the CSV extension from https://github.com/NetLogo/CSV-Extension/tree/cl-test and copied in C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.4\app\extensions\csv but I couldn't get any result.

Comment: I can import the CSV data in NetLogo, I can see them in Command Center part. Is it correct?

Comment: @Sina - 1. The CSV extension comes loaded with the standard NetLogo install, you do not need to copy it anywhere. 2. If you import CSV data into NetLogo, it will not automatically be 'loaded' into the command center, because that's not what the command center is for. The command center allows you to type commands in the console (usually to the Observer) and it outputs the results of commands like `print`, `show`, etc. You have to tell NetLogo to display a variable, for example with the `print data` line in the first example above.

Comment: @Sina - I have added some more info to my answer above- see if that helps.

Comment: @ Luke C- Thanks a lot, I could insert data in NetLogo. In the next step, I must define the data as start and end points of walls and connect them together to make a building plan. I wanna know that how to define this data as a point and make lines between them. My purpose is simulating people behavior in this plan.